# How to configure confirmation email token lifespan in asp.net core mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, password-recovery, email-confirmation

I'm trying to extend the lifespan of both confirmation emails and password reset emails but I can't manage to do so.
Currently I'm using Asp.net core 1.0.1 if that's helpful.

Some tips or even better, the code, would be much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Can you add a code snippet of how you are handling this at the moment?

Comment: Ignas, I followed this link as a reference point: https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/859

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Maybe it will help someone=)

Just do this:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // ...
        services.Configure<DataProtectionTokenProviderOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromDays(2); // Sets the expiry to two days
        });
    }
```

This works for me.

Comment: it's not working in my project. I am using .Net Core 3.1

Comment: Wouldn't this also increase the LifeSpan of the PasswordRest token? I'm pretty sure EmailConfirmation and PasswordReset tokens both use the same instance of DataProtectionTokenProvider.

Answer (score 2):

The following code change in the Create method (in the App_Start\IdentityConfig.cs file) sets the tokens to expire in 3 hours.

```
if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
 {
    manager.UserTokenProvider =
       new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>
          (dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"))
          {                    
             TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromHours(3)
          };
 }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I mentioned that I am using Asp.net core mvc, so there isn't any App_Start\IdentityConfig.cs.

Anyways, thank you :)